# Ruby on Rails: Best way to Iterate a Relation or Associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I see that .where statement make so much request with a lot of **CACHE User Load** message than association. Is this true or not?

In this case I get an **ActiveRecord_Relation:**

```
@dogs = Dog.where(user_id: current_user.id).order('created_at DESC')
```

In this other case, I get a **ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:**

```
@dogs = current_user.dogs.order('created_at DESC')
```

When I iterate in the view

```
<% @dogs.each do |dog| %>
<div><%= dog.name %></div>
<% end %>
```

I get different message in my console log:

**ActiveRecord_Relation:**

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  CACHE User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

**ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:**

```
User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Dog Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "dogs".* FROM "dogs" WHERE "dogs"."user_id" = ? ORDER BY "dogs"."created_at" DESC  [["user_id", 15]]
```

Which is the better way? Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you please include the view code that iterates through the collection?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like in both cases `current_user` should be invoked only once. Presumably the `current_user` method has an implementation like this:

```
def current_user
  # read some cookies or something
  User.find_by([...])
end
```

It's not clear to me why `User.find_by` would be invoked many times in the "ActiveRecord_Relation" version, but that seems like it must be what's happening. Rails is caching the result of this query, so every time after the first time you hit a warm cache.

To rule this out, you can [memoize](http://blog.honeybadger.io/rubyist_guide_to_memoization/) `#current_user`. This should prevent Active Record from every seeing the query after the first invocation of `current_user`.